# Android - PHP or Java Webservice

Tags: java, php, android

I was wondering what peoples thoughts are with using PHP or Java Webserices to connect with MYsql...or any other ways.

Between the two what do you find easier and safer?

Comment: Either works.  Neither has any problem with Android clients.  This site isn't for language wars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PHP is a server-side scripting language` designed for web development but it is used as a general-purpose programming language.

`Java is a general-purpose, concurrent, class-based, object-oriente`computer programming language that is specifically designed to have as few implementation dependencies as possible.
It follows write once, run everywhere rule. It is used to write apps/programs for PCs/mobile devices.

So if you want to write an `app for webserver`, it is definitly a `wise choice to go with PHP`, however you are writing app for `PC/mobile devices`, you should use `Java`.

Java is fairly easy compared to other OO languages. Apps written in it are also safe because they run on JVM, Java virtual machine, so if your app crashes it doesn't crash the whole system. There are alot of other security features as well.

At the end of the day `that language is always easy` to work with, `which you know better, with which you have worked before.`